# how write text/template in a file and include it to project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, texttemplate

I use script `type="text/template"` for my project and I use a lot of templates, I want write my template in foreign file and include it to my html

If its possible , what type of file must i use and how must write it ?

Answer (score 1):

In a pure JavaScript/HTML environment, you can't easily.

Your choices are:

**Use some kind of JavaScript template library**

I'm only familiar with [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/)  that uses the [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) engine.

[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) seems to be another popular choice.

Most of these packages include far more than just templates and may be overkill.

**Use a server-side template package**

[PHP](http://www.php.net/) is a popular server-side tool.

Some HTTP Servers support [Server Side Includes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/ssi.shtml), but these are so limited I couldn't actually recommend them.